# Not able to ping after attaching ENI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I attached an ENI to my Amazon EC2 instance and rebooted it. My EC2 instance now has 2 IP addresses (IP1 and IP2). When I try to ping using IP1 it works but when I use IP2 it is not working.

I have my ENI and EC2 on same VPC, Subnet and Security Group.

Comment: What Operating System are you using? Are they Public or Private IP addresses? From where are you trying to Ping -- from within the VPC or from the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have the new network interface **recognized by the Operating System**.

For example, I did the following:

- I had an instance with an Elastic IP address
- **Test Ping:** Success
- Security Group: I added an ICMP inbound rule
- **Test ping:** Fail
- I added a second ENI and attached an Elastic IP address
- **Test ping to the secondary Elastic IP address:** Fail
- I did a `sudo service network restart` to recognize the additional network interface
- **Test ping to the secondary Elastic IP address:** Success

For more information, see the documentation:

- **Linux:** [Configuring the Operating System on Your Instance to Recognize the Secondary Private IP Address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html#StepTwoConfigOS)
- **Windows:** [Configuring a Secondary Private IP Address for Your Windows Instance in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/config-windows-multiple-ip.html)

Comment: An Elastic Network Interface (ENI) is not the same thing as a secondary address.  If you have an ENI, you have two different interfaces, using different IP's, and they are probably on the same subnet.  To configure this you need to take care of the route asymmetry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298905/how-to-use-a-second-elastic-network-interface-on-the-same-subnet